# Post doesn't show on page feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post facebook status to a page using facebook api. i get array return (id) of those post. but its doesn't show up on page timeline. i try to access facebook feed graph of those page. and i get the result.

fb page : https://www.facebook.com/testscrap?ref=hl (no timeline showing). but i actually have a post accessed from facebook graph ( https://www.facebook.com/348759318542072/posts/350492115035459 )

Where am i going wrong?

here is the code to post :

```
$feed_dir       = "/{$page['page_id']}/feed/";
$msg_body       = array (
        'access_token'  => $page['access_token'],           
        'message'       => 'Jingle bell jingle bell jingle all the way',            
        'picture'       => 'http://assets.kompas.com/data/photo/2012/08/26/0958534620X310.jpg',
    );

try {
    $result = $this->data['fbinstance']->api($feed_dir, 'post', $msg_body);
    jlog($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $err_str = $e->getMessage();
    jlog($err_str);
}
```

Comment: I can see two "Jingle bell .." posts on that wall. Including the one you are linking to directly

Comment: really? i don't see anything there.

Comment: http://d.pr/i/dGfE . Facebook is slow sometimes to update because of caching problems. So it works for me, because I'm not using the same server and haven't visited the page before. (Maybe the answer)

Comment: so why it doesn't show up on my feed? is something problem with session? i try to change several browser. nothing is show up.

Comment: As I said in the other comment, I have experienced caching problems from Facebook on pages and groups, no matter how much I emptied my cache and changes browsers. But it should show up sooner or later. Try with a different user if you have access to it.

Comment: well you should post it as answer of question, so i can vote you up bro :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy from the comment to the authors post:

> As I said in the other comment, I have experienced caching problems from Facebook on pages and groups, no matter how much I emptied my cache and changes browsers. But it should show up sooner or later. Try with a different user if you have access to it.

Facebook might sometimes be slow to update the cache, and therefore be slow to display new posts. So a successful request should work, just test with other users.